# Laravel 5 Vagrant box laravel/homestead give 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

Its been 3 days now, still I am unable to solve this. I have just installed the vagrant box on my Yosemite. I am learning to work with vm. Following the steps over [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) I had installed vagrant box of homestead. But its giveing me 502 Bad gateway. I had set up laravel.local in host file also.

I tried other links for ngnix (1.8.0) but, I am unable to run laravel on homestead vm!!?

This is the output of /var/log/nginx/laravel.local-error.log

```
2015/07/12 18:54:31 [error] 957#0: *20 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: la5.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "la5.dev"
2015/07/12 19:03:07 [error] 1957#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: la5.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "la5.dev"
2015/07/12 19:04:33 [error] 2006#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: la5.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "la5.dev"
```

vagrant@homestead:/var/log/nginx$

And this is my Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: /Users/maahedev/code/la5
  to: /home/vagrant/la5

sites:
- map: la5.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/la5/public

databases:
- homestead

variables:
- key: APP_ENV
  value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

EDIT: output of `netstat -antp`

```
 (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State           PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2477/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57219           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11300         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN          2477/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:50267          ESTABLISHED -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::47876                :::*                    LISTEN            -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Do you have port forwarded from guest to the host?

Comment: can you please explain in detail where to do port forward?

Comment: I am using virtual box and vagrant. I had followed the steps from laravel and vagrant site. But, still its not working.

Comment: Can you reach HHVM out of guest machine via port 8000? In your case Nginx tries to reach port 9000 instead. Official doc says *Each site will be accessible by HTTP via port 8000*

Comment: If you could help me with some comments to run, I would really appreciate it.  I have checked in nginx.conf, there listen 80 is available.

Comment: ok, let's focus on HHVM process that should listen port 9000 on guest machine, try *netstat -antp* and update your question with this output

Comment: when i do `sudo nginx`, i got this error. 
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
...
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()

Comment: you can't run it once it again but rather to reload *sudo nginx -s reload*. By netstat output your PHP process seemed not running, check its configuration, not Nginx fail.

Comment: `php -v` gave this output php -v
PHP 5.6.10-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
    with blackfire v0.24.1, https://blackfire.io/, by SensioLabs

Comment: did you able to start PHP process? What is in the error log?

Comment: how to start PHP process, or how to verify it?

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

from your virtual machine bash, go to the paste /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

there, run `ls -la`

you will see your projects there

run `sudo nano "your project name"`

look for the line: `fastcgi-pass ... php/php7.number...`

update the "number" variable with 2, so you get: `fastcgi-pass ... php/php7.2...`

restart nginx and php services with: `sudo service nginx restart && sudo service php7.*-fpm restart`

than try to run your site again

Answer (score -1):

First fix any permissions problems on your storage folders

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /root/to/yourapp/storage/
```

Also make sure you don’t have any other VM environments running at the same time and shut them down using vagrant halt.This error is most likely because you have a port conflict on your system.

Comment: did you make sure you had no other vm instances using the same ports. This is what was giving me the problems that i had. Open virtual box and see what's running.